# Nested gradle builds

Tags: gradle

I have three projects A,B and C. A depends on B, B depends on C. I currently have following setup:

```
  projectA/
  |__settings.gradle
  |__build.gradle
  |__projectB/
     |__build.gradle
     |__projectC
        |__build.gradle
```

The build fails with error message:

```
Build file '/path/to/projectA/projectB/build.gradle' line: 5

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':projectB'.
> Project with path ':projectC' could not be found in project ':projectB'.
...
```

Is there a way to make gradle work with this folder structure?

The contents of settings.gradle:

```
include 'projectB'
```

Content of projectA/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'hello.projectA'

dependencies {
    compile project(':projectB')
}
```

Content of projectB/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':projectC')
}
```

Content of projectC/build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, to use project dependencies, all projects must be declard in one `settings.gradle` file as members of the same global project, your `projectC` must be included into the root project too, by declaring it in the `settings.gradle` of `projectA`, but as subproject of `projectB`, like:

```
include 'projectB', 'projectB:projectC'
```

And, not really sure now, it could be so, as it has to be declared in the `projectB` dependencies, as `:projectB:projectC`

Comment: Thanks, I got it working. Unfortunately, projectB cannot be compiled independently without modification this way. So I restructured my project to use a flat hierarchy.